# How to add jar files to java project without gradle or Maven or Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar

Can I add a **jar** file to a Java project I created on my desktop manually **without** using gradle, Maven or any dependency management tool or any Java IDE? Currently the project is a single folder containing 5 java files and I run it from the terminal. Is it possible to use a jar dependency in this kind of project. If Yes, please show me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/219801/2003986)

Supposing you have in the root directory of your project a `Test.jar` and a `lib` directory containing jar files :

**Windows**

```
java -cp "Test.jar;lib/*" my.package.MainClass
```

**Unix**

```
java -cp "Test.jar:lib/*" my.package.MainClass
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `-cp` [compiler option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Comment: can you please give a summary of how i'll use that